# Dealing with responsive media queries when printing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, print-css

The issue: https://output.jsbin.com/donapohuci

This is a two column layout on desktop. Using a CSS media query, I have set it to be one column when the viewport is 800px or less:

```
div {
  float: left; 
  width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  div {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

The issue is that when you go to print this (at the moment, using Chrome) it decides that a letter sized piece of paper is smaller than 800px so prints using the media query styles.

We're using Bootstrap where it uses media queries like this. One solution is to modify the CSS so that it adds the 'screen' modifier:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:800px)
```

Alas, this is a giant enterprise project with multiple teams all contributing so we'd really rather not mess with any of the foundational CSS at this time (as that usually causes a domino effect of other issues on other teams...)

Is there a way to workaround this short of writing a separate print style sheet just for this one particular page we need to have printed "as you see on screen"?

I'm thinking along the lines of some way to tell the browser "pretend the paper is wider than it is and use the desktop layout when you print..."

Answer (score 1):

The way I would solve this is by adding the media `screen` attribute in the link to the regular CSS so it doesn't apply to print, and create a separate custom print stylesheet to be called after, again, using the `print` media attribute:

```
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```

It is possible that the default Bootstrap has an include to a print file, but this should be easy to remove, and ultimately if it's not possible the latter stylesheet will still overwrite those styles.

Comment: This will work but falls into the "short of writing a separate print style sheet" comment I made. It's definitely an option, but would be the most work and require us to them keep an additional CSS file in sync with the rest of the CSS layout-wise.

Comment: I think it would still be the better solution in the long term. For more immediate you could always write those styles into a `style` tag and add the media attribute to it: `<style media="print">Stles here</style>`

Comment: oh for sure. It's just that it's a complex page that already consists of several hundred lines of CSS that we'll have to move over into this secondary file and then in the future when one page is redesigned, the print version will have to be updated as well. Which maybe is all we can do. But trying to avoid the technical debt that that solution will bring going forward.